# Подключение шрифта

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Ребята помогите, я уже сгораю и мозги закипают.
Не отображается шрифт, который пытаюсь подключить.

Файл fonts.css

```
@font-face{
            font-family: 'ProximaNovaBlack';
            src: url("fonts/Proxima-Nova-Cyr/Proxima Nova OpenType/ProximaNova-Black.otf") format("otf");
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        };
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Форма отправки</title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <style>

        * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

        html{
            height:100%;
        }

        body {
            height:100%;
            color: white;
            background-color: #1976d3;
            font-size:24px ;
            font-family: "ProximaNovaBlack", sans-serif;
```

Прошу помочь, иначе нервная система не выдержит)))

Comment: devtools -> network. И попробуй заменить пробелы на %20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй изменить тип формата, а так же удалить пробелы в пути (их всегда нужно избегать)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNovaBlack;
    src: url("fonts/Proxima-Nova-Cyr/Proxima-Nova-OpenType/ProximaNova-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я нашел ответ после вашего замечания.